# How to create a node js server socket to receive data in different ports?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I need a socket server that must receive data from 100 clientes in different ports on the server. I've created an array of server sockets and I don't know if this is correct.

I also identified a slowness to receive the data when I have about 100 clients sending data and for some reason the server stops receiving from 10 clients.

Here is my code for 3 ports as an example.

```
var net = require('net');
var rl = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var ports = [60001, 60002, 60003];

var server = new Array();

ports.forEach(function(value) {

    server[value] = net.createServer(function (socket) {    // array of socket servers

        socket.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            server[value].close();
            server[value].listen(value);    //start listen again
        });

        socket.on('end', function() {
            console.log('client disconnected: ' + value);
            server[value].close();
            server[value].listen(value);    //start listen again
        });

        console.log('client connected: ' + value);

        var intf = rl.createInterface(socket, socket);

        intf.on('line', function (line) {

            fs.exists(__dirname + "\\file" + value.toString() + ".txt", function (exists) {

                if(exists){
                    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "\\file" + value.toString() + ".txt", {'flags': 'a'});
                } else {
                    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "\\file" + value.toString() + ".txt", {'flags': 'w'});
                }

                try {
                    stream.once('open', function(fd) {
                        console.log(value.toString() + " - " + line);
                        stream.write(line + "\r\n");
                        stream.end();
                    });     
                } catch (x) {
                    console.log(x.stack);
                }

            });

        }); 

    }); 

    server[value].listen(value);    // listen many ports

});
```

Comment: Have you considered using a reverse proxy for forwarding different ports to one node application port?

Comment: My problem is that this is running in my customer so I have not access to this kind of configuration. My customer said that he can't change any configurations. That's way I'm trying to do something like this.

Comment: Ah this always sucks... Maybe you could reuse the connect listener: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098823/using-node-js-to-listen-on-2-different-ports

Comment: Yes, I change the code posted here and I'm not more using an array of server sockets cause I realize that this is not needed.

Comment: It's working but looks like after connecting the first time the server receive data from clientes but after disconnect and connect again nothing comes from client... I'm working on it to see what is happening... Thank's for help...

Comment: Maybe a timeout? Try using "socket.setTimeout(0)"